# Same x and y to disappear

Tags: java, paint, paintcomponent

I am making a game, but I am having a problem with making some rects disappear.
What happens is that I can move around(finally), but when I get to their x and y thay do not disappear like the should.
When I call **repaint();** , it redraws the player so why does it not also erase the rectangles?


Here is my simple games code:

```
public class GameOne extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    static JFrame f = new JFrame("GAME ONE");
    Timer t = new Timer(5,this);
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    final int rx1 = ((rand.nextInt(19)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int rx2 = ((rand.nextInt(19)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int rx3 = ((rand.nextInt(19)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int rx4 = ((rand.nextInt(19)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int rx5 = ((rand.nextInt(19)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int ry1 = ((rand.nextInt(9)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int ry2 = ((rand.nextInt(9)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int ry3 = ((rand.nextInt(9)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int ry4 = ((rand.nextInt(9)+1)*50) + 5;
    final int ry5 = ((rand.nextInt(9)+1)*50) + 5;
    int x = 480;
    int y = 230;
    double velx = 0;
    double vely = 0;
    boolean one = true;
    boolean two = true;
    boolean three = true;
    boolean four = true;
    boolean five = true;

    public GameOne(){
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.fillRect(0,0,1000,500);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillRect(x - 25,y - 25,50,50);
        g2.setColor(Color.gray);
        if(x == rx1 && y == ry1){
            one = false;
        }
        if(x == rx2 && y == ry2){
            two = false;
        }
        if(x == rx3 && y == ry3){
            three = false;
        }
        if(x == rx4 && y == ry4){
            four = false;
        }
        if(x == rx5 && y == ry5){
            five = false;
        }
        if(one){
            g2.fillRect(rx1, ry1, 50, 50);
        }
        if(two){
            g2.fillRect(rx2, ry2, 50, 50);
        }
        if(three){
            g2.fillRect(rx3, ry3, 50, 50);
        }
        if(four){
            g2.fillRect(rx4, ry4, 50, 50);
        }
        if(five){
            g2.fillRect(rx5, ry5, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public void up(){
        y += -50;
    }

    public void down(){
        y += 50;
    }

    public void left(){
        x += -50;
    }

    public void right(){
        x += 50;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int code = e.getKeyCode();


        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up();
            repaint();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            down();
            repaint();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left();
            repaint();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            right();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        f.setSize(1000,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        GameOne g1 = new GameOne();
        f.add(g1);
        new GameOne();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the values of your variables (one, two, three, four)? If they are true then your rectangles will repaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the x and y never match up to the values of rxN and ryN. For instance, here are the values when the blue box is directly behind a gray one:

```
x = 430 y = 230
rx1 = 555 ry1 = 205
rx2 = 305 ry2 = 105
rx3 = 155 ry3 = 205
rx4 = 905 ry4 = 405
rx5 = 405 ry5 = 205
```

The problem then is in your math. You calculate the x,y of the box from its center point rather than from its upper left but you don't do the same for the gray rectangles. Change the paint to use this series of if statements and it should work:

```
 if(x == rx1 + 25 && y == ry1 + 25){
    one = false;
 }
 if(x == rx2 + 25 && y == ry2 + 25){
    two = false;
 }
 if(x == rx3 + 25 && y == ry3 + 25){
    three = false;
 }
 if(x == rx4 + 25 && y == ry4 + 25){
    four = false;
 }
 if(x == rx5 + 25  && y == ry5 + 25){
    five = false;
 }
```